# Looking for a music player that saves the added/removed songs from the playlist immediately and directly to the playlist file(m3u8)

Tags: music, mp3

I've enjoyed various music players through Ubuntu. From Clementine, Rhythmbox, cantata, Elisa, Rollypop, DeaDBeef... there are many useful, gorgeous, powerful and even light-weighted music players. These have too enriched features to me.

Yet, I didn't meet a music player that fulfills a single missing feature that I need.

I just want to find a player that saves certain changes in the playlist(add/remove/move up and down etc) by me, immediately to the playlist file(using relative path), like Google docs save the change immediately to the doc files in the cloud.

Until now, the "Juk" was the closest to my needs. It can handle many playlists at the same time and save the changes to the file by "just push Ctrl+s". Although saving is not done automatically, It's quite comfortable. But It didn't use the relative path.

Others like Exaile, Quod Libet(with playlist add-on) were good. But the procedure of saving(exporting) to m3u8 file is very troublesome.

If anyone has information about the music player that satisfies this missing part, please let me know.

Comment: Sorry I do not see that this has anything to do with the Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Ive been developing a music player that does this and a whole lot more but it's probably another year until release.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Because I'm a newcomer to Linux, I don't know very well how and where should I ask my questions.

If It's not the right place to ask, please let me know the appropriate place to find an answer.

Another year... It's a very long time, though I could wait for the arrival of WinEunuuchs2Unix's work.

If that time is coming please let me know to have a chance to appreciate your works.